# Move one row value to another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, temp-tables

I currently have a temporary table like so

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
NULL    NULL   1
test1   34.5   NULL
NULL    NULL   2
test1   38.5   NULL
```

I want a script which will make my temporary table as below

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
test1   34.5   1
test1   38.5   2
```

Comment: How do you know that countervalue 2 belongs to the API50 value `38.5`? Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Good question @a_horse_with_no_name! I guess there is some implicit order used and he wants to combine the consecutive rows.

Comment: Hi All, I am using SQL Server 2008.  The counter value always goes first hence it will be applicable to the next row where the count value is null. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has a primary key, and you always want to associate the CounterValue field with the next field in the table, you can do a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.DBName, t1.API50, t2.CounterValue
FROM MyTable t1 INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.PrimaryKey -1 = t2.PrimaryKey
WHERE t1.DBName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Good answer! If the table really has no other columns besides the three shown, you could add a new column to the existing table to provide this functionality. It seems worth the effort.

Comment: @SebastianH, I just noticed that he says he is using a temporary table: it shouldn't be too hard to add a key to that. Good idea.

Comment: That's a perfect solution. Thank you ever so much. It works!.

Comment: Hi, I have used the script above and it works fine however if the counter value ends up to null all the way through the last row is removed.  I have explained further in the following question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626096/move-one-row-value-to-another-sql-without-deleting-the-last-row

Answer (score 0):

I like AHiggins answer as it solves the problem in SQL as it is probably expected. But what initially stuck me when I read your question is: Why solve it in SQL at all?
It seems like the data is not originally created inside the database but somehow imported.
If I am correct - or if exporting the table, editing and re-importing - is an option then you could solve this with a regular expression. All notable text editors can do this for you (I tested this with NotePad++).

If the table is in a text file using a tabulator `\t` as delimiter you could simply replace all

`NULL\tNULL\t(.*)\n(.*)\t(.*)\tNULL`

with `\2\t\3\t\1`.