# move one row value to another sql without deleting the last row

Tags: sql, duplicates

I currently have a temporary table like so

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
NULL    NULL   1
test1   34.5   NULL
NULL    NULL   2
test1   38.5   NULL
```

I want a script which will make my temporary table as below

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
test1   34.5   1
test1   38.5   2
```

I got some help from stackexchange and managed to achieve the above result by using the following script.

```
SELECT t1.DBName, t1.API50, t2.CounterValue
FROM MyTable t1 INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.PrimaryKey -1 = t2.PrimaryKey
WHERE t1.DBName IS NOT NULL
```

However, if the counter value in my table is not populated at all

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
NULL    NULL   NULL
test1   34.5   NULL
NULL    NULL   NULL
test1   38.5   NULL
```

Using the above script the first row is removed (which I don't want) like so

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
test1   38.5   NULL
```

I would want to achieve a result

```
DBName API50 CounterValue
test1   34.5   NULL
test1   38.5   NULL
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is PrimaryKey? Can you provide create table statement and insert statement for some sample data that illustrates your point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226543/move-one-row-value-to-another-sql.  

Thanks.

Comment: The query is giving correct results for the second set of data as well. Have you checked it correctly? Check this fiddle here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b89e0/1. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is nothing to reference the line for the counter value.
The database will want to match things.
What we can do is this...
If the counter value is always the line before the test, we can get the value of the previous line, but there is no guarantee that the results will be accurate since there is no perfect match of test id's and api50's compared to counter value.

Here's the code:

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
    DBName          varchar(5),
    API50           varchar(8),
    CounterValue    integer
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (DBName, API50, CounterValue) select null, null, 1
INSERT INTO @TestData (DBName, API50, CounterValue) select 'test1', 34.5, null
INSERT INTO @TestData (DBName, API50, CounterValue) select null, null, 2
INSERT INTO @TestData (DBName, API50, CounterValue) select 'test1', 38.5, null

Declare @TestData2 TABLE
(
    DBName          varchar(5),
    API50           varchar(8),
    CounterValue    integer,
    myrow           integer
);

INSERT INTO @TestData2 (DBName, API50, CounterValue, myrow)
select  t1.DBName, API50, CounterValue, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as myrow from @TestData as t1

select z1.DBName, z1.API50, z2.CounterValue  

from @TestData2 as z1
left join @TestData2 as z2
on z2.myrow = z1.myrow - 1

where z1.DBName is not null
and z1.API50 is not null
and z2.CounterValue is not null
```

Here is the result:

| DBName | API50 | CounterValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 34.5 | 1 |
| test1 | 38.5 | 2 |