# How to move one row value to another row and remove all rows which are null SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a table as below

```
PK   DBName API50 CounterValue
1    NULL    NULL   NULL
2    NULL    NULL   1
3    NULL    NULL   NULL
4    NULL    NULL   NULL
5    NULL    NULL   NULL
6    test1   34.5   NULL
7    NULL    NULL   NULL
8    NULL    NULL   NULL
9    NULL    NULL   NULL
10   NULL    NULL   2
11   test1   38.5   NULL
```

I would like the result table to be as follows

```
   DBName API50 CounterValue
    test1  34.5   1
    test1  38.5   2
```

As answered in the question below
[move one row value to another sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226543/move-one-row-value-to-another-sql)

Iam doing a self join but it results in CounterValue not being populated. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the **rule**? Show for each `DBName/API50` the previous `CounterValue` not null ? oO What happends when you have many values in `CounterValue` ?

Comment: Hi thanks for looking into this. There will be equal number of counter values to match DBName and API50 always.  Also CounterValue will be populated first and then the DBName and API50 will be populated.  Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226543/move-one-row-value-to-another-sql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626096/move-one-row-value-to-another-sql-without-deleting-the-last-row.. duplicate

Comment: Yes both of the question above are from myself.

Answer (score 2):

If countervalue always increases in line with PK,

```
select
    DBName, 
    API50, 
    (select max(CounterValue) from yourtable t1 where t1.pk <= yourtable.pk)
from yourtable
where DBName is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DBName,API50,
       (SELECT TOP 1
           CounterValue
           FROM t
           WHERE CounterValue is not null
           AND PK<=t1.PK
           ORDER BY PK DESC

        ) as CounterValue
FROM t as t1
WHERE DBNAme IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67679/3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query as well

**Select  t.DBName,MAX(t.API50) as API50,tt.CounterValue from (
Select * from JustTest as t where DBName is not null) as t
,(Select* from JustTest as tt where CounterValue is not null )tt
group by t.DBName,tt.CounterValue

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from @table1
SELECT t1.ID, t1.DBName, t1.API50, t2.CounterValue
FROM @table1 t1 
INNER JOIN @table1 t2 ON t1.ID > t2.ID
WHERE t1.DBName IS NOT NULL
 AND t2.ID IN (select ID from @table1 where dbname is null and ID < t1.ID)
 AND t2.ID > (select ISNULL(MAX(ID),0) from @table1 where dbname is not null and ID < t1.ID)
```

Check this [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a7cb/1)